# Прослушивать изменения в Model из ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Подскажите как прослушивать изменения в Model из ViewModel.

Есть Model

```
public class MainModel : BaseViewModel
{ 
    private string pLink ;
    public string Link
    {
        get => Link;
        set
        {
            pLink = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private string pImage ;
    public string Image
    {
        get => pImage;
        set
        {
            pImage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Есть MainViewModel

```
public class TopViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private readonly Model model;

    public TopViewModel()
    {
        model = new Model();
        model.Link = "https://yandex.ru/";
        model.Image = "https://omoro.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/chernii-smailik-7.jpg";
    }
}
```

Есть вторая ViewModel в которой нужно прослушивать Model.
Пробовал сделать так -

```
public class TwoViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private readonly Model model;

    public TopViewModel()
    {
        model = new Model();
        model.PropertyChanged += Model_PropertyChanged;
    }
    
    private void Model_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ( e.PropertyName == nameof(Model.Link))
        {
            ... 
        }
         if ( e.PropertyName == nameof(Model.Image))
        {
            ... 
        }
    }
}
```

Не работает....

Comment: Вы не показали класс Model. А во-вторых, зачем ее прослушивать? Она как-то сама меняется? Или она меняется после каких-то действий в VM?

Comment: `new Model();` как вы думаете, что делает эта строчка? Вот как поймете, что делает - сразу станет ясно, почему не работает.

Comment: Вы не показали код, который меняет что-то в модели. Может быть, вы меняете не тот экземпляр модельного класса, на который подписались?

Comment: @VladD показано же, это просто разные экземпляры. Он подписывается на 1 экземпляр, а меняет другой. Типичная ошибка новичка, незнакомого с ООП. Еще он показывает сначала класс `MainModel`, затем его перетменовывает, и показывает как `Model` в других кусках кода. В общем, сам запутался, и нас пытается запутать.

Comment: @aepot: А, точно, не заметил

Comment: @VladD вообще это можно пустить как дубликат про данные и 2 формы, ну либо дать простой ответ. Хотя чтобы его дать правильно, надо увидеть зависимость этих вьюмоделей, автор сделал обфускат видимо чтобы сократить код, но выкинул ключевые моменты, тем самым всё усложнив. Хотя наверное можно на своем собственном примере, но мне лень писать свой конкретно для этого вопроса.